# How can I cancel multiple subscriptions at a time in PayPal sandbox?

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am using the test environment i.e. sandbox accounts in PayPal. One of these buyer accounts has many subscriptions as a result of testing from my side.

Now I would like to cancel all these subscriptions, which I can do one at a time, but is there a way to cancel all active subscriptions for a buyer account at a time in PayPal sandbox?

May be there is a way but I could not find it after a lot of research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that PayPal sandbox only allows cancelling one subscription at a time.

However, one effective approach in this situation would be to delete the buyer account associated with these multiple subscriptions, and then create a new buyer account on https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/.  Once you you delete a buyer account, all subscriptions associated with it would also get deleted.